# Fourier series returning a complex number

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, fourier-transform

Suppose I have $f(x) = e^{-\pi x^2}$. Then it can be worked out that
$$\hat{f}(y) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)e^{-2\pi i x y}\mathrm{d}x=f(y).$$

I can represent $f(x)$ as
$$f(x) = \lim_{T\to\infty}\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}c_ne^{2\pi i\frac{n}{T}x},$$
where
$$c_n = \frac{1}{T}\hat{f}\left(\frac{n}{T}\right).$$

Here's what I don't understand. Suppose $x$ is real. Then $f(x)$ is real. Then $\hat{f}(x)$ is real. Then $c_n$ is real.

But $e^{2\pi i\frac{n}{T}x}$ is complex. So every term in the summation is complex.

So does that sum only converge to a real number in the limit case, where (I'd imagine) the complex parts must all cancel out?

Comment: Actually the function that "coincides" with its transform is $e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}$

Comment: Doesn't that depend on how you define the Fourier transform? Either way, it doesn't solve the problem of there being complex numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you consider the Fourier transform of a real valued function $f(x)$ it is easy to see that the definition leads to the following property
$$
\hat{f} (-y) = \overline{\hat{f} (y)}
$$
Since here you also know that the Fourier transform is real, which is always true for a symmetric real function $f(x)$, this automatically implies that $\hat{f}(y)=\hat{f}(-y)$ and hence you get $c_n = c_{-n}$ for the coefficients in your series.

As a results you rewrite the series as
$$
f(x) = \lim_{T \rightarrow \infty} \left[ c_0 + \sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n \left(e^{2 \pi i \frac{n}{T}x} + e^{-2 \pi i \frac{n}{T}x}\right) \right] = \lim_{T \rightarrow \infty} \left[ c_0 + 2 \sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n \cos\left(2 \pi \frac{n}{T}x\right) \right]
$$
which is the sum of only real terms.

So just as you expected the complex terms cancel out, but they do so for every value of $T$.